# How to create a simple interface to view data collected by Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to create a user-friendly interface for users to view data collected by Google Analytics. Their Reporting API v4 looks like a good place to start, but I was wondering if anyone knows of anything existing that I could leverage?

If not, does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What is your use case? What is that you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Try Google's [Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com). You can set up an Analytics View as a data source and then [publish](https://datastudio.google.com/open/0B_U5RNpwhcE6SF85TENURnc4UjA) the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by interface? If you're looking for a report that can be sent out, Supermetrics may be what you're looking for.

If you're looking for a more sophisticated client dashboard, you might be able to leverage PowerBI.

Comment: The main thing I'm trying to show is how many hits the projects on our projects page are getting each. Maybe displayed in a bar graph.

The supermetrics Data Grabber looks good, but I'm unable to spend any money.

Comment: Then try the google drive version of Super Metrics: It's free, but with fewer bells and whistles. 

http://supermetrics.com/product/supermetrics-for-google-drive/ 

Still, what access do you expect the end user to need?

Comment: Just view access. This is just a proof of concept right now. Plan to show it my coworkers and then to clients if it seems like it would be helpful for them. The GA site is too difficult for them to use.

I'll have to try the the Super Metrics for Google Drive at home. My work computer doesn't allow add-ons or extensions to google. Looks like the right path though.

Comment: Glad you like it. SM is very helpful. We use the Excel version for report automation at my Co. each month.  If you like my answer could you mark it correct? :-)